# Why can't apps connect to the internet?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s, data-connection

Running on both WiFi and mobile connection, the browser can connect to the internet ok but apps can not connect.

What can cause this?

Samsung Galaxy S

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Comment: What's your ROM? Have you ever installed Firewall? Or, activated firewall feature of [Avast! Mobile Security](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity)?

Comment: @Sergiy - No phone isn't rooted.

Comment: @Sachin - No. No firewalls or security apps installed. Thought it might be a APN issue at first but had same issues on WiFi.

Comment: If an app can't connect check first the app's permission in `settings/restrict data usage`

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the culprit is much easier to solve: If accessing secured websites (https:) via the browser fails as well, **make sure your date/time settings are correct** -- otherwise certificates will fail. Best explained using an example:

Say, today the date is May 28<sup>th</sup> 2013 -- but your device's date/time is set to January 1<sup>st</sup> 2010. Now you visit a secure website, which is using a certificate issued on June 1<sup>st</sup> 2012 -- valid vor 2 years. Your browser won't accept that certificate, as it must assume it's a fake -- issued in the future. Same would apply if your browser's date were set too far in the future, e.g. December 31<sup>st</sup> 2014: the certificate would look "expired" to the browser, which again would not accept it.

Same applies to your apps, which often use a secured connection (hopefully!). Just unsecure connections (not using certificates) would work fine -- which explains why your browsers work on many sites.

Comment: this is the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a software problem. Try a hard reset - that should restore connectivity. Note that **this will delete all your data**, so [back it up](https://www.google.de/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enDE466DE466&aq=0&oq=backup%20and&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=backup%20android%20phone) first. When installing apps back try to check connectivity after each new installation - in this way you'll be able to determine what causes the problem.

Also as a random guess - do you use a proxy that only permits web-pages (only HTTP protocol)? That would explain why your browser works, but apps do not (they often use other protocols than HTTP).

Comment: When you say "hard reset" do you mean "factory reset"?   A hard reset means to turn off and on again, which will not delete any data.

Comment: Yes. I meant "factory reset".

Comment: this is an infeasible solution

Comment: it is feasible when all else fails... although I admit it's time-consuming

Answer (score 2):

Disabling the 'data connection' and then enabling it solved my problem. You should try it. You can alternatively try toggling the airplane mode (or use a [widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guywmustang.airplanewidget&hl=en)) that should also enable and disable the data connection (both WiFi/data).