# Connection problems 3G/4G (Mobile data)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, connection-issues, data-connection, mobile-data

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S3, Mobile data enabled, APN configured for T-mobile

Applications: MightyText, BrowserTexting

Internet connection is working, i can use browsers, gtalk, IMO, etc. The problem is some applications cant connect to their respective servers. 
Both apps work when on WiFi, but not when using mobile data connection.

The question is how to debug this problem? Is there a way to see what the problem is, see the request, responses?

Update:
The behaviour seems to be sporadic. While the above mentioned apps have never been able to connect, now Imo is having problems signing in.

Help please

Comment: You could check your `logcat` for hints. A trivial reason might be the device having an incorrect date/time setup (make sure date and time reflecting the current date and time; if the offset between reality and setup is too large, it might cause apps to reject returned data packages as being "out of range").

Comment: I have checked the date and time, it is current.
The odd thing i have also noticed, the gmail app doesnt notify me about new emails when connected via Mobile data, but when on WiFi it does.

Comment: Would have been to easy a solution... You might want to consult some related questions: [Apps can't connect to internet](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36377/16575) and [Why can't apps connect to the internet?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20728/16575) describe similar issues.

Comment: I have just checked those questions and checked the suggestions. AutoSyinc is enabled, background data is not disabled. I have tried to manually sync my google account and some of the tabs have synced but these havent: Calendar, Contacts, Internet. Any ideas?