# Unable to access internet

Tags: connection-issues

Previous day i installed an app on my mobile (Micromax superfone) .It is not compatible with my mobile it said,but it continue the installation process. From that time i was unable to use all kind of internet based apps on my mobile except through browser. What is the solution for this problem??
Please suggest.
Thanks you.

Comment: Can you try to uninstall the app?

Comment: Already i done with unistalling that app but no use !!

Comment: Have a look at the answers on [Why can't apps connect to the internet?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20728)